# Callback hook is not running after a dependency has changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to set focus after transition has ended and have written the following code

```js
const [transitionEnded, setTransitionEnded] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
        console.log("state: ", transitionEnded);
    }, [transitionEnded])

const inputRefCallback = useCallback((el) => {
        console.log("called", transitionEnded);
        if(!el) {
            return;
        }
        if(inputRef.current) {
            return;
        }
        if(!transitionEnded) {
            return;
        }
        if(shouldDelayFocus) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                focusAndUpdateMultilineInputRange(el);    
            }, CONST.ANIMATED_TRANSITION);
        }
        else focusAndUpdateMultilineInputRange(el);
        inputRef.current = el;
        
    }, [transitionEnded]);

......

<ScreenWrapper
            onEntryTransitionEnd = {() => {
                console.log("transition ended");
                setTransitionEnded(true);
            }}
        >

<TextInput
  ref={inputRefCallback}
```

I'm getting the following logs,

[image]

What I want is, callback to run again after the state has updated and do the focus correctly

Comment: You assigned `inputRefCallback` to the `ref` prop so it will run only when the `<TextInput />` mounts

Comment: how do I make it run the state update?  I tried calling it again after setting the transition state to true, but it didn't work @Konrad

Comment: Put it in the `useEffect`

Comment: `useCallback` doesn't call the function when `transitionEnded` updates, if that's what you're expecting?

Comment: Yes I'm expecting the callback method to be called after `transitionEnded` updates, also, on changing it to useEffect, I'm getting undefined in the `el` object which I need to set the focus @Konrad

Comment: `useCallback` redefines the callback when `transitionEnded` updates. You'll likely need to use `useEffect` and add an event listener in addition to the `useCallback`.

Comment: if the method inside useCallback runs after the state update, i'll achieve what I desire here @evolutionxbox its the last step which is not happening because of something

Comment: The `useEffect` isn't firing because `transitionEnded` isn't changing.